# How to detect if an object as at least two properties valued?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have many javascript objects which are like:

```js
{
  "id": "123",
  "name": undefined,
  "other": undefined,
  "and": "so on",
  ... and many others, each time different fields
}
```

But most of the time the fields can be all `undefined` except `id` (which is always `!= undefined`).

I would like a method to detect if an object has **AT LEAST ONE valued prop BESIDES "id"**.

What do you recommend?

Comment: You really should show more effort at trying to solve the issue at hand, you are asking how to do it, without showing any effort. I recommend showing code that you have tried in order to solve ***" AT LEAST ONE valued prop BESIDES "id"***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
const a = {
  "id": "123",
  "name": undefined,
  "other": undefined,
  "and": "so on",  
}

const b = {
  "id": "123",
  "name": undefined,
  "other": "bla",
  "and":  "bla",  
}

const c = {
  "id": "123",
  "name": undefined,
  "other": undefined,
  "and":  undefined,  
}

const hasValue = obj => Object.entries(obj).some(([k,v]) => k!=='id' && v!==undefined)

console.log(hasValue(a))
console.log(hasValue(b))
console.log(hasValue(c))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use for in loop. In the loop we put condition that key can't be id and other keys cannot be undefined. **For Example  :**

```js
function detectTwoValuedProperty(obj) {
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (key !== "id" && obj[key] !== undefined) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

const objectOne = {
  "id": "123",
  "name": undefined,
  "other": undefined,
};

const objectTwo = {
  "id": "456",
  "name": "Fred Hors",
  "age": undefined,
};

console.log(detectTwoValuedProperty(objectOne)); // return false
console.log(detectTwoValuedProperty(objectTwo)); // return true
```